# If $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U(0,X)$ what is the density (distribution) function $f_Y(y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U(0,X)$ what is the density (distribution) function $f_Y(y)$?

I know the answer and I also found it on this site (link bellow). However, I just can't get the intuition why the last integral boundaries become from $y$ to $1$?

Step by step solution attempt:

$f_Y(y)=\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} f_{Y,X}(y,x)dx=\int_\mathbb{R} f_{Y|X=x}(y)f_{X}(x)dx=\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{X}dx=^{?}\displaystyle\int_y^1\frac{1}{X}dx=-\ln(y)$

[Let. X∼U(0,1). Given X=x, let Y∼U(0,x). How can I calculate E(X|Y=y)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738765/let-x-sim-mathcalu0-1-given-x-x-let-y-sim-mathcalu0-x-ho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support of the joint pdf is $0< Y<X <1$

Clearly to "integrate out" $X$ to obtain the marginal pdf of $Y=y$ requires integrating w.r.t. $x$ over the interval $y<x<1$

$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) ~=~& \int_\Bbb R \frac 1 x ~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;x),x\in(0;1)}~\operatorname d x 
\\[1ex] =~& ~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1)}\int_y^1 \frac 1 x ~\operatorname d x 
\\[1ex] =~& -\ln y~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1)}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The equality :

$\int_\mathbb{R} f_{Y|X=x}(y)f_{X}(x)dx=\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{X}dx$ 
is incorrect

it should be :

$\int_\mathbb{R} f_{Y|X=x}(y)f_{X}(x)dx=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^y0dx+\displaystyle\int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}dx+\displaystyle\int_1^{+\infty} 0dx$

as for $x \leq y$ , $f_{Y|X=x}(y)=0$
and for $x \geq 1$ $f_X(x)=0$